# Why is an expression of type unit expected?

Tags: ocaml

Given a date between 2010 and 2019, the function is supposed to return an int 0 though 6 corresponding to Sunday through Saturday. The function is based on the fact that January 1, 2010 was a Friday.

Why does the else statement toward the end `else if year = 2019` elicit the error for its entire body: "This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type unit"?

```
let day_of_week (year: int) (month: int) (day: int): int =
  if year < 2010 || year > 2019 then failwith "year out of range"
    else if month < 1 || month > 12 then failwith "invalid month"
    else if day < 1 then failwith "invalid day"
    else if is_leap_year year != true then (
            if month = 2 then (
                    if day > 28 then failwith "invalid day"
            )
    ) else if month = 2 then
            if day > 29 then failwith "invalid day"
    else if month = 4 || month = 6 || month = 9 || month = 11 then
            if day > 30 then failwith "invalid day"
    else if day > 31 then failwith "invalid day"
    else if year = 2010 then (
            if month = 1 then ((day mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2011 then (
            if month = 1 then (((365 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((365 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((365 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((365 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((365 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((365 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((365 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((365 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((365 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((365 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((365 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((365 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2012 then (
            if month = 1 then (((730 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((730 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((730 + 60 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((730 + 91 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((730 + 121 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((730 + 152 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((730 + 182 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((730 + 213 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((730 + 244 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((730 + 274 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((730 + 305 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((730 + 335 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2013 then (
            if month = 1 then (((1096 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((1096 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((1096 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((1096 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((1096 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((1096 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((1096 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((1096 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((1096 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((1096 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((1096 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((1096 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2014 then (
            if month = 1 then (((1461 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((1461 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((1461 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((1461 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((1461 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((1461 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((1461 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((1461 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((1461 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((1461 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((1461 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((1461 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2015 then (
            if month = 1 then (((1826 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((1826 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((1826 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((1826 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((1826 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((1826 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((1826 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((1826 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((1826 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((1826 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((1826 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((1826 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2016 then (
            if month = 1 then (((2191 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((2191 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((2191 + 60 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((2191 + 91 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((2191 + 121 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((2191 + 152 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((2191 + 182 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((2191 + 213 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((2191 + 244 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((2191 + 274 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((2191 + 305 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((2191 + 335 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2017 then (
            if month = 1 then (((2557 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((2557 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((2557 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((2557 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((2557 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((2557 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((2557 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((2557 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((2557 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((2557 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((2557 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((2557 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2018 then (
            if month = 1 then (((2922 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((2922 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((2922 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((2922 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((2922 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((2922 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((2922 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((2922 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((2922 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((2922 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((2922 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((2922 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    ) else if year = 2019 then (
            if month = 1 then (((3287 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 2 then (((3287 + 31 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 3 then (((3287 + 59 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 4 then (((3287 + 90 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 5 then (((3287 + 120 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 6 then (((3287 + 151 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 7 then (((3287 + 181 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 8 then (((3287 + 212 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 9 then (((3287 + 243 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 10 then (((3287 + 273 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else if month = 11 then (((3287 + 304 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
            else (((3287 + 334 + day) mod 7) + 4) mod 7
    )
```

Comment: I would _strongly_ recommend you read up on what it means to write functional code and try to incorporate that into your code. To put it bluntly, that is a mess.

Comment: Hahah I understand, but the exercise forbade loops and recursion.

Comment: You can solve it with very simple math which doesn't use loops/recursion. This code won't pass the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is this line:

```
if day > 28 then failwith "invalid day"
```

There's no `else` part. A missing else part is equivalent to `()`, which leads to the typing problem.

In fact the compiler is right. This code will in fact return () for non-leap years on days other than Feb 29, it seems to me.

One possible fix would be to change the section of code to this:

```
else if is_leap_year year != true && month = 2 && day > 28 then failwith "invalid day"
else . . .
```

As a side comment, `is_leap_year != true` is more clearly expressed as `not is_leap_year` in my opinion.

(As another side comment, Jeff Mercado is correct. You would never write code like this in a real project. There are many ways to do far better.)

Comment: After I did @JefferyScofield's fix I still had the problem, but I solved it by changing `else if year = 2019 then` to just `else`.